# can any body help me redirecting this page

Tags: php, mysql

When file is submitted successfully, it should redirect to `malangwaview.php` which is located at another folder. Can any body help me.

```
<?php

  $query = "INSERT INTO malangwa(
            id,fullname, address, contactno, bikemodel, bikeno, problem, partsifanychanged, partsprice, nextservice, followupby, remarks
            ) VALUES (
                NULL,'{$fullname}', '{$address}', '{$contactno}','{$bikemodel}','{$bikeno}','{$problem}','{$partsifanychanged}','{$partsprice}','{$nextservice}','{$followupby}','{$remarks}'
            )";

    if(mysql_query($query, $connection)){
        //sucess
        header("Location: /malangwaview.php");
        exit;

    } else {
        //Display error message
        echo "<p> Subject creation faileld. </p>";
        echo "<p>" . mysql_error() . "</p>";
    }
?>

<?php mysql_close($connection);?>
```

Comment: Any errors currently?

Comment: so its getting to the else? or something other is happening?

Answer (score 2):

```
header("Location: another_folder_path/malangwaview.php");
```

or

```
header("Location: ../malangwaview.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, You can redirect to any page with HEADER. In your case, it should be something like :
`header( "Location: http://www.domain.com/another_folder/malangwaview.php" );`